# TableviewCells with different contents

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, cell, nsuserdefaults

im trying to make an App where the User can add a Cell and where he can add different Contents to the Cell like Name, Birthday and Hobbys for example. 
So far so good. 
But how can i show him the individual Contents of each Cell?
Do I have to add a ViewController with different labels, where i load the text saved for the specific cell, for example with NSuserdefaults/Coredata?
Or am I totally wrong?

What i have right now : in my viewController where i can add an item

```
@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    name = txtFieldName.text!
    vc.items.append(name)
    vc.tableView.reloadData()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil)
}
```

in my tableviewController:

```
  var items = [String]();

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(items)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("itemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code to make this question clearer.

Comment: well now how can i save the data for each cell, while creating it  and how can i load each cell with the different contents.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement kinda this thing

NavigationController ->(segue) TableView or TVController ->(show item segue) TableView or TVController

Using this example we should have files for each tableview and cell 
first pair(newsvc.swift newscell.swift) 
second pair(newsitemvc.swift newsitemcell.swift)

So as we understand it's a MVC

We need implement some static data
Create Model file (add struct and initialize  it)

```
struct News {
    var time: String?
    var title: String?
    var text: String?

    init(time: String?, title: String?,text: String?) {
        self.time = time
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

in second file we create data for struct

```
let newsData = [ News(time: "10:00", title: "Test", text: "Some text"),
                 News(time: "11:00", title: "Test1", text: "Some text1")]
```

NewsCell.swift

```
class NewsCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

  var news: News! {
    didSet {
      timeLabel = news.time

      titleLabel = news.title

      textLabel.text = news.text
    }
  }
}
```

in NewsViewController we need add "News" array and make it get data from "newsData"

```
var newsItems: [News] = newsData
```

update functions

```
  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsItems.count
  }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsCell
    let news = newsItems[indexPath.row] as News
    cell.news = news
    return cell
  }
```

after it we should add segue

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if segue.identifier == "showItemSegue" {
      if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NewsItemViewController {
      let seguedArray = newsItems[indexPath.row] as News
      destViewController.newSeguedArray = seguedArray
      }
    }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, and how do i save the data for the created  cell? Can i use NSuserdefaults or do i have to user CoreData

Comment: @Korken55 now you understand?

Comment: well I will Try this. I'm not at home right now. Thanks for that one

Comment: can my Second File be a UIViewController, where the user can give the data for the vars like time and text ? Cause my problem is that i want to save data for each cell the user creates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111557/discussion-between-korken55-and-dmitry-petukhov).

Answer (score 0):

You would append the data to an array before setting it to said cell. You can pull this data based on what they clicked by using the index in the array and the `index.row` variable.